# System restore Windows with Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: linux, operating-systems, window

I currently have dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu on different partitions. If I were to do a system restore on Windows 10 where I pick the option to delete all files, will the dual boot (Ubuntu partitions) be affected?

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not affect the Ubuntu partition as it is concerned just with Windows.

I always myself have good backups in case there is an issue, but there should not be.

Windows restores and repairs itself if possible (mostly is) without formatting and so without issue to other partitions.

Comment: As @John mentions, a full disk image should remove any lingering doubt. You can use either Linux or Windows apps to make the image. For example, Macrium Reflect can image and restore both Windows NTSF and Linux ext4 partitions (and other formats for boot, etc.) all at the same time (though Windows will not be able to mount the ext4 image for viewing without a third-party tool).